# how to find the difference of median price of a municipality from the current month and the next one?

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to get the absolute difference between the median house price for tat month in that municipality and the median house price for the next month in that municipality?
I have a table with house data. it contains the price and municipality for each house and date it got sold. I want to get the difference of the median price for a municipality of a month and median price of the house for municipality of the next month. Already created the median function.
This is my query at the moment:

```
select gemeentenaam as municipality, 
       EXTRACT(MONTH FROM datum_ondertekening) as month, median(koopprijs) as median_price_previous_month, 
       LEAD(median(koopprijs)) OVER(PARTITION BY gemeentenaam) AS median_price_next_month, 
       ABS((LEAD(median(koopprijs)) OVER(PARTITION BY gemeentenaam))-(median(koopprijs))) AS difference 
from funda 
  inner join postcode on funda.postcode = postcode.postcode 
  inner join gemeente on postcode.gemeente = gemeente.gemcode 
WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM datum_ondertekening) <> 12 
group by (gemeentenaam, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM datum_ondertekening), koopprijs);
```

EDIT:

sample data:

```
globalid | postcode | koopprijs | datum_ondertekening
----------+----------+-----------+---------------------
 4606495  | 4701CV   |    595000 | 2019-03-01
 4607492  | 5252AV   |    329000 | 2019-01-11
 4562176  | 3454VC   |    292500 | 2019-08-26
 4562213  | 3454VC   |    337500 | 2019-01-25
 4557050  | 3774BM   |    439000 | 2019-03-08


 postcode | gemeente
----------+----------
 1231SW   |     1696
 1723MX   |      416
 2111XN   |      377
 3648HN   |      736
 4053JP   |     1740


 gemcode | gemeentenaam
---------+--------------
       3 | Appingedam
      10 | Delfzijl
      14 | Groningen
      24 | Loppersum
      34 | Almere
```

expected result:

```
 municipality  | month | median_price_previous_month | median_price_next_month |    difference
---------------+-------+-----------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------
 's-Gravenhage |     1 |         100000.000000000000 |     105000.000000000000 | 5000.000000000000
 's-Gravenhage |     2 |         105000.000000000000 |     110000.000000000000 | 5000.000000000000
 's-Gravenhage |     3 |         110000.000000000000 |     115000.000000000000 | 5000.000000000000
 's-Gravenhage |     4 |         115000.000000000000 |     119000.000000000000 | 4000.000000000000
 's-Gravenhage |     5 |         119000.000000000000 |     119500.000000000000 |  500.000000000000
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: check the edit please @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found it myself.

````
select gemeentenaam as municipality, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM datum_ondertekening) as month, median(koopprijs) as 
                media_price_next_month, LAG(median(koopprijs)) OVER(PARTITION BY gemeentenaam) AS median_price_previous_month, 
                ABS(median(koopprijs)-(LAG(median(koopprijs)) OVER(PARTITION BY gemeentenaam))) AS absolute_difference 
        from funda 
            inner join postcode on funda.postcode = postcode.postcode 
            inner join gemeente on postcode.gemeente = gemeente.gemcode WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM datum_ondertekening) <> 1
            group by (gemeentenaam, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM datum_ondertekening));```
````